# can oplog detect data view changes in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to detect any data changes in the view, `oplog` can detect data changes on view.

Are there any ways to detect data view is changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by **data changes in view** ? will you please give some example.

Comment: when data from another collections changed, data in view changed too, because those collections used in view query. @Mani

Comment: So basically there is some update happens in a collection, this will be captured in oplog.

Comment: @Mani Well, oplog can capture data changes in view separately such as a collection?

Comment: Data change in view happens only when data changes in the collection. So all data changes are captured in oplog.

Comment: @Mani I think oplog can not capture view, it captures collection only. in the ns (namespace) field of oplog,just wirte database and collection name ,view log won't be written in oplog.

Comment: @Mani recently we had AWS CDC task to be done. We wanted to capture on going data changes in a "View".

The question is does oplog records changes in a "View?